# Get the x-Coordinate in a ScrolledForm SWT

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, pixel, jface

I've got a problem with SWT `Table` and the JFace `TableViewer`.
I need to know on which column a right-click was performed. Unfortunally, the `TableColumn` and `TableViewerColumn` do not recognize a right-click event.

So I found this "hack" to check where the mouse click was performed on the screen, get the y-Coordinate and add the width of each table column as long at the value is smaller than the y-Coordinate.

If the y-Coordinate is in between the added widths, the last column added is the right clicked one. See below.

```
    int width = 0; // the start point. 0 only works if not scrolled

    final TableColumn[] sorted = new TableColumn[table.getColumns().length];
    final int[] order = table.getColumnOrder();
    int ctn = 0;
    for( final int i : order )
    {
      sorted[ctn] = table.getColumn( i );
      ctn++;
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < table.getColumns().length; i++ )
    {
      final TableColumn tc = sorted[i];


      if( (width < point.x) && (point.x < (width + tc.getWidth())) )
      {

       rightClickedColumn = tc; // the colums is in the range, so this is the one clicked on

      }
      width += tc.getWidth(); // add the width of this columns so we can check the next one
    }
```

This works fine, as long as the composite holding the `TableViewer` is not scrolled.

When it is scrolled, the start value of 0 is not correct anymore, it has to be the difference between the original 0 and the first pixel which is visible from the table.
So if 100px of the table are  not visible, I want to get this 100px. How can I get the position of the first visible pixel in a scrolled composite?

Hope you understand what I mean

**Edit:** I need to get notified when a **table column header** was right-clicked

Comment: Are you doing this to display a context (right click) menu?

Comment: No. A context menu is shown. In this, you can activate a column. This colum should be added after the one on which the right click was performed. As said, this works when nothing is scrolled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `TableColumn#getWidth()` you should work with `TableItem#getBounds()` to determine the column you are in.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    ScrolledComposite comp = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
    comp.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Table table = new Table(comp, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
        column.setText("Column " + i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++)
        {
            item.setText(j, "Item " + i + "-" + j);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        table.getColumn(i).pack();
    }
    table.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener()
    {
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            Point pt = new Point(event.x, event.y);
            TableItem item = table.getItem(pt);
            if (item == null)
                return;
            for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++)
            {
                Rectangle rect = item.getBounds(i);
                if (rect.contains(pt))
                {
                    int index = table.indexOf(item);
                    System.out.println("Item " + index + "-" + i);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    comp.setContent(table);
    comp.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    comp.setExpandVertical(true);
    comp.setMinSize(table.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(400, 600);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

It will display the selected table cell (row and column).

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to listen for click events on the table headers, replace the first `for` loop with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    final TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    column.setText("Column " + i);
    column.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            System.out.println(column.getText());
        }
    });
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Detecting right click on the `Table` header is a bit more tricky. There is a bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23103) saying that `SWT.MenuDetect` cannot be used on `TableColumn`s

However, there is a workaround:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    ScrolledComposite comp = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
    comp.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Table table = new Table(comp, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        final TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
        column.setText("Column " + i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++)
        {
            item.setText(j, "Item " + i + "-" + j);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        table.getColumn(i).pack();
    }

    table.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            Point pt = display.map(null, table, new Point(event.x, event.y));
            Rectangle clientArea = table.getClientArea();
            boolean header = clientArea.y <= pt.y && pt.y < (clientArea.y + table.getHeaderHeight());

            if (header)
            {
                TableItem item = table.getItem(0);
                for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++)
                {
                    Rectangle rect = item.getBounds(i);
                    if (pt.x >= rect.x && pt.x <= rect.x + rect.width)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Header " + i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    comp.setContent(table);
    comp.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    comp.setExpandVertical(true);
    comp.setMinSize(table.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(400, 600);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that the column headers do not get the event

Comment: @verbose-mode Updated my answer again. It now detects right click on the `Table` header.

Comment: Thanks, will check it on monday!

Comment: @verbose-mode Excellent!

Comment: Ok, encountered a new problem here: If the table is empty, this will cause an error (since we use a TableItem)

Comment: @verbose-mode True, but do you need a menu when the table is empty?  If not, you can simply disable the menu. If so, I don't have a solution. You may want to open a new question in that case.

Comment: Yes, because the table is filterable  will open a new question